# iPhone UIView element similar to the lock screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Does anyone know if there is an open source project for an UIView element that acts in a similar way to the lock screen for the iPhone.

I am working on an app that has some sensitive data, and I want to add another layer of comfort for users, to be able to setup a 4 digit pin number on the app.

I've seen apps like LoseIt and Weightbot that have similar functionality.

There isn't any element for this in the UI Library from what I've been able to find, and was hoping some kind soul might have open sourced something similar to this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andiih above for the answer, because I found an open source version on GitHub based on the name of the one he found.

http://github.com/haroldthehungry/CPLockController

Answer (score 1):

Its not a free component, but check out http://www.drobnik.com/touch/parts-store/ the DTPinLockController - I think this does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found an open source one.

Answer (score 1):

And another open source one (BSD license) is at:

https://github.com/Krishna/Lock-Screen

Comment: I tried both the free ones and this ones appears to be further in development. Thats why I upvoted this one. But if you want a good starting point try the other.